# Grails: search using createCriteria

Tags: grails

I need to do simple search (Two my example-simple domains and controller action are below). I want to return list of users with firstName, lastName or Car.carName like searchPattern

```
   class User {
        String firstName
        String lastName
        static hasMany = [car : Car]
    }

    class Car {
    User user
    String carName
    }

     def list(String search){
...
     def searchPattern = "%" + search + "%"
     def domains = User.createCriteria().list(max: max, offset: offset) {
                or {
                    like("firstName", searchPattern)
                    like("lastName", searchPattern)
                    car {
                       like("carName", searchPattern)
                       }

    }
    }
```

It returns incorrect results -  doesn't see user, which hasn't got car. Can you help me to change it for correct working? Thanks a lot

Comment: `car` must be written in lower case

Comment: I didn't get it, what you want your query to return...

Comment: injecteer, yes, I edit it here (mistake by copy), but it doesn't decide problem

Comment: I want to return list of users with firstName, lastName or Car.carName like searchPattern

Comment: try replacing `like`s with `ilike`s. maybe it's case problem

Comment: no, result is the same. My problem is that I get only users,  which have Car and don't get users without (all the rest in search is good).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set up the domain class associations correctly. It seems you're going for a *has-many* association between `User` and `Car`. There are two variations: uni-directional and bi-directional. However, your implementation uses neither. Going with the assumption that you want a bi-directional association, you'll need to modify your `Car` class like this:

```
class Car {
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
    String carName
}
```

And for clarity, since a `User` has many `Car`s, it'd be worth pluralizing the collection name:

```
class User {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    static hasMany = [cars : Car]
}
```

For more on associations, you can read [my article](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/) on the subject.

Next, since you want `User`s even if they do not have `Car`s, you should know about a subtle default built into GORM: the SQL database tables are automatically *INNER JOIN*ed. It is this *INNER JOIN* that's causing `User`s without `Car`s to be ignored. To address this, you'll need to change the  join to an *OUTER JOIN*. You can do something like this:

```
import static org.hibernate.sql.JoinType.*

def domains = User.createCriteria().list(max: max, offset: offset) {
    createAlias('cars', 'c', LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)

    or {
        like("firstName", searchPattern)
        like("lastName", searchPattern)
        like("c.carName", searchPattern)
        isNull("c.carName")
    }
}
```

If I recall, aliases are used differently, hence the `c.carName`. You can read a bit more about using a LEFT OUTER JOIN [here](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-from-clause/).

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
car{
  or{
    isNull 'carName'
    like 'carName', searchPattern
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to all for your help and for usefull links. This decided my problem:

```
    import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification
.....

    def domains = User.createCriteria().list(max: max, offset: offset) {
    createAlias('cars', 'c', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)

    or {
        like("firstName", searchPattern)
        like("lastName", searchPattern)
        like("c.carName", searchPattern)
    }
```